# What is the chronological relationship between Nehemiah chapter 10 and 13?

Tags: chronology, nehemiah

In Nehemiah 10, the people made the decision that "they will not *give their daughters* to the peoples of the land or *take the peoples of the land's daughters for their sons*" (v.30), and that they will now "*keep* the sabbaths" (v.31).
The chapter concludes with the statement: "Thus we will *not neglect the house of our God*" (v.39)

Yet, in chapter 13, Nehemiah restores the sabbath (v.15 ff), and he makes the people swear (again?) to "not give the daughters to their sons, nor take of their daughters for the sons or for yourselves." (v.25)
In verse 11, Nehemiah asks "Why is the house of God forsaken?"

So, chapter 13 adresses the three main points of the resolution of chapter 10.

Does chapter 13 depict a situation that is chronologically after chapter 10? This would indicate that the people quickly forgot their resolution and Nehemiah hat to fight yet again for these points.

Or does rather chapter 13 depict the situation chronologically before chapter 10 that then lead to chapter 10's resolution?

Comment: More than 10 years had passed between the two chapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred twice:

Once at entering: 11:1 ¶  And the rulers of the people dwelt at Jerusalem: the rest of the people also cast lots, to bring one of ten to dwell in Jerusalem the holy city, and nine parts to dwell in other cities.

And once at the dedication: 
12: 27 ¶  And at the dedication of the wall of Jerusalem they sought the Levites out of all their places, to bring them to Jerusalem, to keep the dedication with gladness, both with thanksgivings, and with singing, with cymbals, psalteries, and with harps.

Somewhere in between they had gathered others to join them, I am not sure where they came from or if they were part of the first group or not.  However, re-dedication to God is a common thing in Israel because they were often forgetful.